# Vue Router route parameters with keywords with slashes

Tags: vue-router

I'd like to configure the Vue Router in such a way that I can efficiently define the following route without duplicating too much code:

```
/course-design/course/{c-id}/instance/{i-id}/module/{m-id}/unit/{u-id}
```

I want the parameters to be optional, but I want to keep the keywords (course, instance, module, unit) for readability of the URL, as they are filter settings, so the following routes are also possible:

```
/course-design/course/{c-id}/instance/{i-id}/module/{m-id}/unit/{u-id}
/course-design/instance/{i-id}/module/{m-id}/unit/{u-id}
/course-design/module/{m-id}/unit/{u-id}
/course-design/unit/{u-id}
/course-design/course/{c-id}/unit/{u-id}
/course-design/module/{m-id}/unit/{u-id}
```

So, basically I want them to be query parameters but then with slashes instead of the ?course=1&module=1

Does anyone have any idea on how to accomplish this? What I currently have is the following, but has a lot of code duplication:

```
const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/course-design/',
    component: CourseDesign,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Course Design',
        component: FolderComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'course/:courseid',
        component: FolderComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'instance/:instanceid',
            component: FolderComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'module/:moduleid',
                component: FolderComponent,
                children: [
                  {
                    path: 'unit/:learningunitid',
                    component: FolderComponent,
                    children: [],
                  },
                ],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'instance/:instanceid',
        component: FolderComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'module/:moduleid',
            component: FolderComponent,
            children: [
              {
                path: 'unit/:learningunitid',
                component: FolderComponent,
                children: [],
              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'module/:moduleid',
        component: FolderComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: 'unit/:learningunitid',
            component: FolderComponent,
            children: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        path: 'unit/:learningunitid',
        component: FolderComponent,
        children: [],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just focus on removing duplication, you can keep the children in the variables.
Here's an example:

```
const learningRoute = {
        path: 'unit/:learningunitid',
        component: FolderComponent,
        children: [],
      };
const moduleRoute = {
            path: 'module/:moduleid',
            component: FolderComponent,
            children: [
              learningRoute,
            ],
          };
const instanceRoute = {
            path: 'instance/:instanceid',
            component: FolderComponent,
            children: [
              moduleRoute,
            ],
          };

const routes: Array<RouteConfig> = [
  {
    path: '/course-design/',
    component: CourseDesign,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        name: 'Course Design',
        component: FolderComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'course/:courseid',
        component: FolderComponent,
        children: [
          instanceRoute,
        ],
      },
      instanceRoute,
      moduleRoute,
      learningRoute,
    ],
  },
];
```

You can make even a function that makes a route if you want to reduce the code more.